# Yii2, elasticsearch. How to assign my _id as primaryKey

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

i'm newbie so I hope you can help me.
I have yii2 and i need to implement elasticSearch(ES).
All set up.
I made standart model and standart CRUD. Just a few changes to implement ES like

```
use yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord;
```

But I have a problem with getting _id in my view/index.php
to get _id in view.php i made

```
$model->_id = $model->primaryKey;
```

But how I can fix it with DataProvider in index.php?

my attributes

```
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        '_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'created',
        'brand',
        'product',
        'qty',
        'sum'
    ];
}
```

My rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'created',
            'brand', 'product', 'qty', 'sum'
        ],
            'safe'],
        [['qty'], 'integer'],
        [['sum'], 'double'],
        ['email', 'email'],
    ];
}
```

I think it should work like with MongoDB, but it doesn't.

if I want to delete or view or update the data being on index.php I can se only such links w/o id

```
http://yii2.dev/index.php?r=elastic%2Fdelete&id=
```

Pls help

P.S.
Here is a var_dump

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(frontend\models\Elastic)[67]
      private '_id' (yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord) => string 'AVreA6SUvBgWLKxTzUZn' (length=20)
  private '_score' (yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord) => float 1
  private '_version' (yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord) => null
  private '_highlight' (yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord) => null
  private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=8)
      'created' => string '2017-03-12' (length=10)
      'first_name' => string 'Luka' (length=4)
      'last_name' => string 'Signori' (length=7)
      'email' => string 'l.signori@gmail.com' (length=19)
      'brand' => string 'Apple' (length=5)
      'product' => string 'iPad' (length=4)
      'qty' => string '35' (length=2)
      'sum' => string '600.00' (length=6)
  private '_oldAttributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=8)
      'created' => string '2017-03-12' (length=10)
      'first_name' => string 'Luka' (length=4)
      'last_name' => string 'Signori' (length=7)
      'email' => string 'l.signori@gmail.com' (length=19)
      'brand' => string 'Apple' (length=5)
      'product' => string 'iPad' (length=4)
      'qty' => string '35' (length=2)
      'sum' => string '600.00' (length=6)
  private '_related' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_errors' (yii\base\Model) => null
  private '_validators' (yii\base\Model) => null
  private '_scenario' (yii\base\Model) => string 'default' (length=7)
  private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set.good luck

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
       'query' => $query,
       'key' => ['your primaryKey']
       'sort' => [
          'defaultOrder' => ['datetime'=>SORT_DESC]
     ],
]);
```